# How can I add my UserControl to my NugetPackage?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, nuget-package

I have published a simple nuget package that includes an UserControl, but when I install my nuget package it says my usercontrol is not found.

If I change the properties for my usercontrol to Embedded Resource I can't even see my usercontrol.

Well, the question is: How can I implement a UserControl.cs and xaml for a nuget package that is made for UWP project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're creating a class library with a simple user control, you'll have these files as build output.

[image: Build output]

WinRT specific files like .xbf have been around since Windows 8 and [.xr.xml](http://www.bartlannoeye.com/blog/update-your-nuspec-file-to-include-xr-xml-files-in-your-nuget-package) since Windows 8.1 and have to be included in your NuGet package as well.

Some files (.dll, .pdb and .pri) go under the lib/uap10.0 folder, while others (.xbf and .xr.xml) go under a subfolder with the name of your assembly.

[image: NuGet package structure]

You can either write the nuspec yourself, use the [NuGet Package Explorer](https://npe.codeplex.com/) to create it or any other 3rd party tool.